# How to store mostly-empty data?

Tags: php, mysql, performance, translation

I want to set up a system that allows for, say, 200 different translations per post. However most translations wouldn't exist, so there'd be a lot of empty datasets. How much of a performance and storage hit is it if I save every language (including empty ones) as a specific column? I.E.

```
English | Arabic | Mandarin | Russian | French         | German

Potato  |        |          |         | Pomme de Terre |
Orange  |        |          |         | Orange         |
Peach   |        |          |         |                |
```

I wouldn't cycle through the whole list very often, I'd use a session variable or usersetting and then load directly from that column if it exists, with a fallback to a default language, and perhaps after that a full search.

```
if (exists(french))
     {echo french}
else {if(exists(english))
          {echo english}}
     else {echo links to non-null language}
     }
```

I'd assume that, if I tell the server which column to go to, the overhead in terms of processing would be negligible? I also assume that an empty cell would be negligible in terms of storage? However I don't know for sure, and it could potentially be a huge mistake.

The reason I'd want to work like this is so I could assign language codes, instead of every installed instance having a different order (e.g. english|french|german|mandarin versus english|mandarin|german|french).

To prevent XY-problems, here's a more global formulation:
I want to set up a system that *allows* for many languages, but I expect that in most cases only 1 or two are used. What would be an efficient way to store?

Answer (score 2):

Keyword: Relational database.

You will want to use multiple tables.
Let's say that the default langauge is english, then your "words" table will implicitly contain the english words.

```
Words:
Id | Word 
1  | Potato
2  | Orange

Languages:
Id | Name
1  | Norwegian
2  | Danish

Translations:
Word | Language | Translated
   1 |    1     |  Potet
   2 |    1     |  Oransje
   1 |    2     |  Kartoffel
   2 |    2     |  Appelsin
```

Then you can do (pseudo sql, you can look up the language and word ids first, or use a more advanced query):

```
SELECT Translated FROM Translations WHERE Word = (the word id) and Language = (the language id)
```

This comes with the benefit that it's very simple to list all the languages you support, all the Words you support, and also all translated words for a specific language (or, find all NON translated words for a language).

A specific query for translating "Potato" into "Danish" would look like:

```
SELECT Translated FROM Translations
  JOIN Words ON Words.Id = Translations.Word
  JOIN Languages ON Languages.Id = Translations.Language
WHERE
  Languages.Name = "Danish" and Words.Word = "Potato"
```

Comment: That is a many:many relationship using 3 tables.  It could be simplified by using the 'standard' 2-letter country-codes, or the "locales" such as `de_AT` for Austrian German.